# Code coverage .net core web application targeting net452

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xunit, visual-studio-2017

How can I get code coverage for a .net core web application which targets net452 in VS2017 (or VS2015)?

I have my tests set up with xUnit but I get no coverage results for the .net core web application. The tests run fine, but I get no coverage!

Is this a known issue?

It doesn't work with MS's test library either.

Quick to repro:

1. Load up VS2017
2. Create new ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET
   Framework) called `WebApplication1`
3. Create `TestClass.cs` as below
4. Create new Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) called `UnitTestProject1`
5. Add reference to `WebApplication1` in `UnitTestProject1`
6. Edit `UnitTest1.cs` as below
7. Run `Test -> Analyze Code Coverage -> All Tests`
8. Open `Test -> Windows -> Code Coverage Results`
9. Code coverage only shows `unittestproject1.dll`

---

TestClass.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public bool TestMethod(bool test)
        {
            if (test) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

UnitTest1.cs

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var testClass = new WebApplication1.TestClass();
            var val = testClass.TestMethod(true);
            Assert.IsTrue(val);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: MS says : Requirements
Visual Studio Enterprise

Comment: That's what I'm running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code coverage is not implemented for netcore projects yet. This
>   support requires datacollectors infrastructure
>   (https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/309) . It will come post
>   RTW. We recommend that you follow the above issue for updates and fix
>   notifications.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/5813/cannot-get-test-coverage-for-net-core-projects.html